# Error When Collecting Reddit Data With PSAW

Tags: python, dataframe, praw

I'm trying to collect the latest Reddit comments using the PSAW library:

```
from psaw import PushshiftAPI
api = PushshiftAPI()
my_reddit_comments=api.search_comments(filter=['id','author', 'body', 'subreddit'],limit=100000)
data=pd.DataFrame(k.d_ for k in my_reddit_comments)
```

I keep receiving the following error:

> ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes
> read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be about Pushshift's query limit. I wrote this to overcome that:

```
while True:
  try:
    my_reddit_comments=api.search_comments(filter=['id','author', 'body', 'subreddit'],limit=100000)
    data=pd.DataFrame(k.d_ for k in my_reddit_comments)
    break
  except:
    print('Vahid is speaking: Max Retries reached. Sleeping for 1 minute',flush=True)
    time.sleep(60)
```